# I would like to upload a youtube video on FB as native video and I want it to autorun

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, autoplay, autorun

I would like to post a youtube video on my Facebook page, I used http://yt2fb.com/ to look like a native one and I would like it to autorun when I scroll down the page

I've downloaded http://www.thunderpenny.com/ and add autoplay=1 but it doesn't publish the video.

Do you have any suggestions?

Best
Sly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be a programming question, but rather about the use of a certain platform/tool.

Comment: what does it mean to you to be a "native" video?

Comment: ok I would like to post a youtube video on FB and I would like it to be displayed as full width. Since I think it's necessary a part of code/programming I thought that this forum was the right one, if not I apologise